# Set Colors of Different Points when Clicking on Pie Slice Legend

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I would like to set all colors for the pie slices to gray except for the color pie slice clicked in the legend. I have been only able to figure out how to change the color of only the clicked legend item not the others.

I have tried setting id's to the data points and using e.target but that didn't provide the proper access.

Thanks for your help.

Here is my [myFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/copperspeed/bLjL9/1/).

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var myCharts = {
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            type: 'pie',
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1)',
            borderColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1)',
            margin: [38, 20, 20, 20],
            width: 300,
            height: 300,
            shadow: true,
        },
        colors: [
            '#0066FF',
            '#33CC33',
            '#FF0000',
            '#FFFF00',
        ],
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        legend: {
            layout: 'horizontal',
            align: 'center',
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            x: 0,
            y: 0
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Net Activations',
            verticalAlign: 'bottom',
            y: 10
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: '7%',
            verticalAlign: 'middle',
            y: 30,
            style: {
                color: 'black',
                fontSize: '40px'
            }
        },
        yAxis: {
            tickColor: '#FF0000',
            tickWidth: 3,
            tickInterval: 5
        },
        xAxis: {
            tickColor: '#FF0000',
            tickWidth: 3,
            tickInterval: 5
        },
        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                states: {
                    hover: {
                        enabled: false
                    }
                },
                point: {
                    events: {
                        legendItemClick: function () {
                            this.graphic.attr({
                                fill: '#CCCCCC'
                            });
                            return false
                        }
                    }
                },
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    distance: 0.1,
                    color: 'black',
                    formatter: function () {
                        return '<b>' + this.point.name + '</b>: ' + this.percentage + ' %';
                    },
                },
                innerSize: '60%',
                shadow: true,
                size: '100%',
                allowPointSelect: true,
                slicedOffset: 10,
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            enabled: false
        },
        series: [{
            data: [],
            showInLegend: true,
        }]
    };
    myCharts.chart.renderTo = 'container';
    myCharts.title.text = 'Net Activations';
    var actual = 52,
        goal = 73 - actual,
        ATB = 100 - goal - actual;
    myCharts.series[0].data = [{
        name: 'Actual',
        y: actual,
        id: 0
    }, {
        name: 'goal',
        y: goal,
        id: 1
    }, {
        name: 'ATB',
        y: ATB,
        id: 2
    }];
    new Highcharts.Chart(myCharts);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of attacking the SVG directly with `this.graphic.attr`, you'd be better off using the API to update the slice.  [Point.update](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Point.update) works well for this:

```
legendItemClick: function () {
    var series = this.series;
    for (var i=0; i < series.data.length; i++){
        var point = series.data[i];
        if (point == this){
            // set back to old color
            point.update({color: series.chart.options.colors[this.id]});
        }else{
            // make it gray
            point.update({color: '#CCCCCC'});
        }
     }
     return false;
 }
```

Updated fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/bLjL9/2/).

Comment: I want that this will happen when I hover on legend. Please give me the solution. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well, I can get you 50% of the way there:

```
point: {
   events: {
       click: function () {
           if (event.point.sliced) {
               $.each(this.series.data, function (i, e) {
                   if (!e.sliced) {
                       this.graphic.attr({
                           fill: '#CCCCCC'
                       });
                   }
               });
           }
        }
    }
```

This still breaks when you re-click the slice to slot it back in - the colors of the other slices are still grey until you click on them. Will need to look more into this.